# Is there a way to specify \ as a character and not an escape character in JSON?

Tags: json

I want to copy a file in sub folder using npm script in package.json. I can copy it using windows command prompt by **copy src\index.html**. But, when I add this in JSON, the `\` is used as a escape character in JSON. So, its giving me an error. How can I specify `\` in JSON? Or is there any other way to copy files using windows commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include `\` in a JSON string, you escape it with a backslash: `\\`.

In your example that would be `copy src\\index.html`.